# Exception in connecting grails app with Oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, grails

I see this exception repeated in logs while booting grails app on Glass Fish server. Database is Oracle.

```
SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20001: DBT Error in AUDIT_SESSION_TRIG
ORA-06512: at line 20
ORA-01653: unable to extend table DBT.SESSION_AUDIT by 1280 in tablespace DBT_DATA_5G

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to insufficient space available in the oracle database for tablespace `DBT_DATA_5G` as it cannot auto extend the size of the tablespace due to restrictions set while creating the tablespace itself (or it is unable to find free contiguous space of 1280). Based on the tablespacename, we may be able to infer that it has been allocated `5GB` of space , but its full now. 
Please contact your DBA to increase the size of the tablespace to fix this error.

If you have access at the DBA level, this query can help you validate the above facts

```
        select * from DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS where tablespace_name='DBA_DATA_5G'
```

Your DBA will probably have to do one of the following as described [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01653_unable_to_extend_table_string_string_by_string_in_tablespace_string.htm)